# How to build windows store app for device independent pixel (DIP)

Tags: window, windows-store-apps, density-independent-pixel, scalable

i am building windows store app. I am using windows 8 and WPF with visual studio .net 2012.

UI of this application should be scalable to different screens. I have created a page where the controls (buttons, images, texts) fits correctly when running the app on simulator with resolution 1920 x 1080 for 10.6" screens. The problem is that when i change resolution, controls do not behave correctly

- when resolution or screen sizes are increased (ex. 1920 x 1080 for 23" screens) empty spaces are created on the page;
- when resolution or screen sizes are decreased (ex. 1024 x 768 for 10.6" screens) controls sizes are increased too and some of them are not visible in UI because they are displayed too far in bottom.

Is there a way to build "scalable" store app which are independent of screen sizes or resolution? Control sizes and font sizes should increase and decrease when resolution change or from one screen to another but all of them should fit in the space and shouldn't create empty areas.

Any help would be very appreciated.

thank you

Answer (score 3):

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780612.aspx) discusses the guidelines for scaling to screens. 
it touches on Screen size, Screen resolution, and Aspect ratio. It provides a table which shows best practices recommended for apps that use scale-to-fit functionality and it touches on adaptive layout. there is a reference to [Guidelines for layouts] at the end of the article as well.

Hope this helps!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780612.aspx

joelcitizen